# Drop bad data from dataset Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.data.dataset

I have a training pipeline using tf.data. Inside the dataset there is some bad elements, in my case a values of 0. How do i drop these bad data elements based on their value? I want to be able to remove them within the pipeline while training since the dataset is large.

Assume from the following pseudo code:

```
def parse_function(element):
    height = element['height']
    if height <= 0: skip() #How to skip this value

    labels = element['label']
    features['height'] = height

    return features, labels

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(ds_files)
clean_ds = ds.map(parse_function)
```

A suggestion would be using ds.skip(1) based on the feature value, or provide some sort of neutral weight/loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tf.data.Dataset.filter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter):

```
def filter_func(elem):
    """ return True if the element is to be kept """
    return tf.math.greater(elem['height'],0)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(ds_files)
clean_ds = ds.filter(filter_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `element` is a data frame in your code, then it would be:

```
def parse_function(element):
    element = element.query('height>0')

    labels = element['label']
    features['height'] = element['height']

    return features, labels

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(ds_files)
clean_ds = ds.map(parse_function)
```

`